# Optimal integer encoding that still sorts

Tags: math, comparison, compression, string-comparison

One of the neat characteristics of UTF-8 is that if you compare two strings (with <) byte-by-byte, you get the same answer as if you had compared them codepoint-by-codepoint. I was wondering if there was a similar encoding that was optimal in size (e.g. UTF-8 "wastes" space by tagging bytes with 10xxxxxx if they are not the first byte representing a codepoint).

The assumption for optimality here is that a non-negative number *n* is more frequent than a number *m* if *n* < *m*.

I am most interested in knowing if there is a (byte-comparable) encoding that works for integers, with *n* more frequent than *m* if |*n*| < |*m*|.

Comment: Please have a look at book stack compression http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move-to-front_transform

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "more frequent". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @NayukiMinase In order to determine optimality we must have a notion of frequency. An encoding is optimal if the sum((symbol's frequency) * (symbols length)  for all symbols) is minimized. I purposefully didn't formalize my question, as I'm really looking for any information on sortable encodings.

Comment: I am very well aware that you are trying to encode integers. If you are looking for a specific encoding then you need to provide a specific distribution. If you are looking for a general encoding, then the algorithms used for UTF-8 and UTF-16 are good choices for encoding sortable items (like integers or characters).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck A simple optimization to UTF-8 is to remove the 10 at the head of bytes after the first one. Varint style encoding saves one bit over UTF-8 after that. UTF-8 "wastes" a little space in order to invalidate certain byte sequences, and allow you to iterate over a string backwards (very intelligent tradeoffs, IMO). But I have not seen an answer to a question like: given the frequency of symbols an an ordering on them, construct a code that minimizes encoded length and maintains bit-by-bit comparison between strings.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Disregard my previous comment, you're right, that does allow you to compare the sequences normally. It's just not an encoding.

Comment: @U2EF1: Is it important for you to be able to search sub-sequences? E.g. UTF-8 is a bit more wasteful than it could be just to allow unambiguous sub-string searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered a variant of Huffman coding?  Traditionally one recursively merges the two least frequent symbols, but to preserve order one could instead merge the two *adjacent* symbols having the least sum.

Looks like this problem has been well-studied (and the greedy algorithm is not optimal).  The optimal algorithm was given by Hu and Tucker, which is described [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~shor/PAM/hu-tucker_algorithm.html) and more detail in this [thesis](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~std3246/thesis/index.html).

This [paper](http://www.vldb.org/journal/VLDBJ6/70060026.pdf) discussing order-preserving dictionary-based compression also looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are very few standard encodings and the answer is no. Any further optimization beyond UTF-8 should not be referred to as "encoding" but a "compression" - and lexicographically-comparable compression is a different department.

If you are solving a real-world (non-purely-academic) problem, I'd just stick with the most standard UTF8. You can learn about its efficiency compared to other standard encodings on utf8everywhere.org.

Comment: This is why I didn't tag this question as unicode, both the answers think I'm trying to encode text when I'm trying to encode streams of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To fully answer that question you need to know the frequency of the codepoints in the material.
UTF-8 is optimal for texts in English as multi-byte characters are very rare in typical English text.

To encode integers using UTF-8 as a base algorithm would entail mapping the first n integers to a 1-byte encoding, the next m to a 2-byte encoding and so on.
Whether that is an optimal encoding depends on the distribution. If the first n numbers are very frequent compared to higher numbers, then UTF-8 would be (near) optimal.

Comment: I'm not encoding text, but numbers; smaller magnitude numbers are considered more frequent. Saying UTF-8 is optimal for English text seems a bit naïve, as it ignores variable-width encodings and multibyte characters which are used in English.

Comment: My point is that there is no encoding that is optimal for all distributions. If your distribution is similar to that of typical English text, then UTF-8 is a good choice. If you have a much wider range of high-probability numbers then UTF-16 is better. Without knowing the distribution it is impossible to tell whether a specific encoding is good or not.